# SQL SERVER, SELECT statement with auto generate row id

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone happen to remember the function name used to generate sequential row number built-in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are making use of GUIDs this should be nice and easy, if you are looking for an integer ID, you will have to wait for another answer.

```
SELECT newId() AS ColId, Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM table1
```

The newId() will generate a new GUID for you that you can use as your automatically generated id column.

Comment: Short and sweet exactly what I needed.

Comment: This does not work for joins or CTE - newId will be always different

Comment: GUID is not a row number

Answer (score 23):

Here is a simple method which ranks the rows after however they are ordered, i.e. inserted in your table. In your SELECT statement simply add the field

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(GETDATE() AS TIMESTAMP)) AS RowNumber.
```

Comment: this gives me an `alias was found before` + `unexpected character` error when i try to run the query (https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/44790691/80913380-747f1700-8d44-11ea-946f-09ec53fb0c85.png)

Answer (score 15):

This will work in SQL Server 2008.

```
select  top 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tmp.FirstName) ,* from tmp
```

Cheers

Comment: the question is about `sql2000`

Answer (score 14):

IDENTITY(int, 1, 1) should do it if you are doing a select into.  In SQL 2000, I use to just put the results in a temp table and query that afterwords.

Comment: Thanks!  This was just what I was looking for.  (You have a typo, it should be "IDENTITY(int, 1, 1)".)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an integer id

This has worked for me:

```
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY newId())
    FROM anyTbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an incrementing integer column returned with your recordset? If so: -

```
--Check for existance  
if  exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where [id] = object_id(N'dbo.t') AND objectproperty(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)  
drop table dbo.t
go

--create dummy table and insert data  
create table dbo.t(x char(1) not null primary key, y char(1) not null)  
go  
set nocount on  
insert dbo.t (x,y) values ('A','B')  
insert dbo.t (x,y) values ('C','D')  
insert dbo.t (x,y) values ('E','F')

--create temp table to add an identity column  
create table dbo.#TempWithIdentity(i int not null identity(1,1) primary key,x char(1) not null unique,y char(1) not null)  

--populate the temporary table  
insert into dbo.#TempWithIdentity(x,y) select x,y from dbo.t

--return the data  
select i,x,y from dbo.#TempWithIdentity

--clean up  
drop table dbo.#TempWithIdentity
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this perhaps what you are looking for?

> select NEWID() * from TABLE

Comment: The OP was asking for a sequential number. Not a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly in SQL2000, as per Microsoft's page: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;186133

```
 select rank=count(*), a1.au_lname, a1.au_fname
   from authors a1, authors a2
   where a1.au_lname + a1.au_fname >= a2.au_lname + a2.au_fname
   group by a1.au_lname, a1.au_fname
   order by rank
```

The only problem with this approach is that (As Jeff says on SQL Server Central) it's a triangular join. So, if you have ten records this will be quick, if you have a thousand records it will be slow, and with a million records it may never complete!

See here for a better explanation of triangular joins: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/

---

Answer (score 0):

```
Select (Select count(y.au_lname) from dbo.authors y
where y.au_lname + y.au_fname <= x.au_lname + y.au_fname) as Counterid,
x.au_lname,x.au_fname from authors x group by au_lname,au_fname
order by Counterid --Alternatively that can be done which is equivalent as above..
```